# Keeping all the api endpoints at one place

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react project and I have to call a lot of backend api in the application. So I have a component and I call the required api from that component. So like this I have api urls in every third component. Is there any best practice for keeping all the urls at one place and use them in components when needed?

Comment: I would say maintain a constant file for that in which you can list down all your api endpoints with some variable name,  then you can use that variable for API after importing it into your Component file.

Comment: Don't know much about react but yes, it's best practise to keep things that are common in a program in one place. It makes it easier if they were to change as you'd only have to update one file instead of multiple.

Comment: I'd say have a single file (or directory with files) with functions responsible for calling your api and returning a promise. Then whenever you need to access api, just import the api file and call the required function. This way your components would not be littered with API URLs and your call logic would be centralized. Even with this approach, keep at least your base URL in a separate config file, or use any other means of keeping it centralized, so that you don't go changing it in every function when it changes.

Comment: @VincasStonys How should I include a base url in my config file?

Comment: Just have a simple constant or a json file.
`const API_URL='example.com'` in some file like constants.js or
`{ "API_URL": "example.com" }` in some json file. Then simply import it in your api files whenever you need to get config data.

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this

I have api folder inside my project where I write my all api request.
I group api calls depending on their work and put in separate js file for exammple:

> userapi.js (all login/logout and other user management relate api
>   calls)

So my userapi looks like

```
export const login = (params) =>{
  //login code
}

export const register = (params) =>{
  //registeration code
}
```

I put all configuration variable in separate file `config.js`.
And then finally in `index.js` I import all those function and export it so that I can access all of them via one place that is `index.js`